# GNOME System Monitor: Resources tab: Graph duration now shows 5 mins instead of 60 seconds, require guide to reduce graph duration

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, system-monitor

GNOME System Monitor v40.1

Graphs are now showing 5 mins, instead of usual 60 seconds. This is after a reboot today, without any user intervention or modification. I am unable to bring it back to 60 seconds. What I have tried:

- Hamburger Menu > Preferences > Resources > Chart Data Points > values between 30 to 600
- Hamburger Menu > Preferences > Resources > Update Interval > 1.00 seconds default
- `dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor/graph-data-points 15`, even tried 1, 3, 6, etc., still not useful.

Please help on how to reduce it down to 60 seconds.

[image]

**EDIT:**

1. I notice my 20.04.2 LTS machine has two System Monitors, the default icon that I usually launch through system drawer menu is v40.1 (this is the one currently giving problems), while the v3.36.1 (inside Utilities sub-folder) runs without above issue. For now I am resorting to using the latter for my monitoring, though I would really like to know the solution to the issue faced in v40.1.
2. The `Graph Data Points` is not shown in Preferences menu for 3.36.1, while is shown in 40.1.